# JSONPath union to extract from an array or a single object

Tags: jsonpath

Our third-party API returns data inconsistently, in one case it gives an array of JSON objects like (if "info" key has multiple elements):

```
{"info": [{"key": "data1"}, {"key": "data2"}]}
```

If "info" has only one element they give you just a JSON object, not array:

```
{"info": {"key": "data1"}}
```

We need to construct a JSONPath to extract the list of "key" elements, so to cover the first case it would be:

```
$.info[*].key
```

For the second case it's

```
$.info.key
```

I tried the union expression to cover both cases in one expression, but it doesn't work in neither online JSONPath demos nor in our Java implementation. It will return an empty list:

```
$.[info[*].key,info.key]
```

I probably misunderstand the syntax for the union expression [,] or it can be only applied when there is no nested wildcard expressions.
Wondering what would be a solution that would extract a list of keys for both scenarios in one expression.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following expression that seems to work for both cases:

```
$.info[key]
```

Note, this works in online JSONPath parsers, but not in our Java solution using json-path-2.2.0.jar